# Sealing a cooktop to the counter? Manufacturer says no

Tags: kitchens

I'm in the process of installing a Wolf CG365T/S gas cooktop, and according to the manufacturer's instructions, I am specifically instructed *not* to seal the cooktop against the counter.

I'm inclined to defer to the manufacturer, especially when it is called out specifically, but I'm also concerned about having no barrier between the top surface and the electrical connections and drawer contents below.

Can anyone provide some insight into why the manufacturer would specify this? Is this a common advisory for drop-in cooktops? Is it to mitigate a specific known issue that is caused when you seal (with caulk or some kind of gasket) the cooktop?

I'd like to make an informed decision, and decide for myself whether leaks or whatever the manufacturer is concerned about is the bigger risk. I may contact their support line come Monday, but I'm not optimistic I'll be able to reach anyone with any real knowledge.

Comment: What is the counter made of?  If you're not sealing the hob to the counter you should protect the cut edges unless they're made of something waterproof. As you don't normally flood the worktop, the areas that get wet would be quite limited. Are you sure there's no built-in gasket?

Comment: The counter is an engineered silestone. It does come with a roll of gasket material, but it is extremely thin and not anywhere close to being thick enough to come in contact with the cooktop if installed as recommended by the manual (which is brief and not very clear). It says to place it around the perimiter of the cutout, and the diagram has it set back from the outer edge of the cooktop meaning it would not actually touch the underside of the cooktop flange. At most it would create a <1mm ridge, protecting against only the smallest of spills that might seep under the edge of the cooktop.